# Is it possible for a user to modify site javascript in browser?

Tags: javascript, security

I don't know a lot about security, but I'm trying to figure out how to keep my site as safe as possible. I understand that as much stuff that I can handle on the backend the better, but for instances where I'd like to hold some variables on the client, is that stuff utterly unchangeable?

For instance, if I set a global variable to the user's role (this is a pure AJAX web app so a global variable is always available), is it possible by any software to edit javascript within the browser so that a user might change their role?

Comment: Assume that 150% of everything clientside is accessible and changeable. Because it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Security is a big topic in the web development world and it is important for you to determine how secure your web application should be.

There are 3 parts for you to notice

1. Frontend (the website)

> everything here is insecure, whatever shown on you in the browser could be changed or modified. Just go to the debug console and you could change the variable and rerender the html page again

2. Transportation level (https)

> web communication is based on the http(s) protocol that allows you to communicate between your server and client. Using `https` will prevent you from man in the middle attack

3. Backend

> always make sure to authenticate and check the data sent from your client (POST, PUT, DELETE)

**Prevention**

The good thing is even you change the variable of the client side, it only appears on that client session and doesn't effect any others. There are few ways you could increase your security in your frontend

1. Obfuscate

> this means make your source code harder to read. You could try to use tool like minification, and concatatenata your source code.

2. Data

> Never ever store user sensitive data (password, user info) in the client side, since people could just change and see it

This should get you learning more about security

Comment: "*it only appears on that client session and doesn't effect any others.*" - that is, if the backend is written properly.

Answer (score 0):

With developer tools if you run in debug mode with breakpoints then you can change values of variables.

Comment: You can also have apps or bookmarklets that can access global variables

Answer (score 0):

All data that goes to the client can be viewed and tampered. There are alot of ways to do that (Developer Tools, HTTP Proxy, ...).